# Face recognition using Fisher Faces OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I used the following code for face face recognition using OpenCV python. Although I had resized the images I still get an error as images should be resized.  How to solve it ?

```
import cv2, os
import numpy as np



recognizer = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer() # Eigenface Recognizer

def get_images_and_labels(path):

   image_paths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]

   images = []
   labels = []

   for image_path in image_paths:

      image_pil = cv2.imread(image_path,0)

      image = np.array(image_pil, 'uint8')

      indx = os.path.split(image_path)[1].split(".")[0]

      images.append(image)
      labels.append(int(indx))

      cv2.imshow("Adding faces to traning set...", image_pil)
      cv2.waitKey(50)

 return images, labels


 path ='G:\Resizing\Fisher Faces\data'

 images, labels = get_images_and_labels(path)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()

recognizer.train(images, np.array(labels))

print "The system has trained successfully."




cascPath = "G:\Resizing\lBPH\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

   ret, frame = cap.read()


   gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=10,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
      )

   for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
     cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

     cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

   for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
      resized = cv2.resize(gray[y: y + h, x: x + w], (200,200), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
      img=cv2.equalizeHist(resized)

      nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(img)

      print "Index {} is Correctly Recognized with confidence {}".format(nbr_predicted, conf)



cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error is

```
"OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 1228800 elements, but got 40000.) 
      in cv::Fisherfaces::predict, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\contrib\src\facerec.cpp, line 623
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Resizing/Fisher Faces/FisherFaces.py", line 79, in <module>
    nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(img)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\contrib\src\facerec.cpp:623: error: (-5) Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 1228800 elements, but got 40000. in function cv::Fisherfaces::predict"
```

Comment: It would help to include the exact error message you're getting, ideally a full stack traceback.

Comment: The code is edited by adding the error message

Comment: Seems fairly self-explanatory. Some of the images would seem to have different dimensions.

Comment: But I'm resizing them with the equal hist function.Isn't that give the images with same size ?

Comment: Code indentation doesn't look quite right. Possibly a conflict with the frame captured with `cap.read()` ?

Comment: I checked it. But still the same error

Comment: Unfortunately your posted code is not in itself sufficient to allow others to reproduce the problem, given that it relies on external data. The numbers are quite telling. The 40,000 (200 x 200) would seem to indicate that at least some of the input is being rescaled, although it's impossible to tell without seeing the external data. The 1,228,800 (probably 1280 x 960), implies one of its sources is not 200 x 200. My guess would've been your capture device, but it could equally be due to an image which hasn't been resized for some reason. Again, there's not enough info in the question to tell.